# How to save small files from nodejs to nginx server?

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs application  that generates images and then saves them on to a Web server to be loaded by browser clients.

I’m wondering what is the most effective way to save files directly from node JS on to the Linux server that is running in nginx.

I’m trying to avoid as much configuration/programming as possible, so trying to find the simplest possible way to get  files from one machine to the other.

FTP seems too slow. SCP seems too cumbersome.  Maybe I need to write some upload code on the engine X machine so I can post a Files onto it. Wondering if anyone has any better suggestions?  Maybe SMB? Or maybe NFS?

Comment: Create a service in your prefered langage on the destination server, then call it from nodejs

Answer (score 0):

For those who might come later.

My goal was to find a simple way to upload files onto a web server.

Easy to program, minimal configuration.

In the end I went with nginx and used its webdav module which made it very easy and met all my goals.